# hash join inside a sas pass through query

Tags: hash

I'm using a sas pass through query to join 7 tables. I'm doing a left join on a key variable that is in all the tables. The tables contain hundreds of millions records.
The code runs for hours and sometimes completes the join, but at other times crashes.
I tried using a hash join, but some tables have 100 variables. So the hash join crashes because it pulls all the variables. Is there a way to code the hash join that will select certain variables in for the results table?
I tried using hashexp:20 but that didn't work either.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,
-rachel

Comment: Yes, change the semicolon in line 42 to a comma. That will fix it.